# Displaying data in WPF in the desired order

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've the following xaml code in my C#/WPF app.

I need to be able to display the contents of View1 after those textblocks and textboxes.Instead, the contents of View1 are now appearing after StackPanel contents.
What am I missing here please?
Thanks for your help.

---

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:MainViewModel="clr-namespace:MyTool.ViewModel"
        xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:MyTool.ViewModel.MyProducts"
        xmlns:View="clr-namespace:MyTool.View" x:Class="MyTool.MainWindow"
        xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:MyTool.View.MyProducts"
        xmlns:v="clr-namespace:MyTool.View.MyProducts"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyTool.ViewModel.MyProducts"
        Title="{Binding DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}" ResizeMode="CanResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <MainViewModel:MyViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="28" Width="auto" Margin="5,0,0,0">

        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Security Type" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultTextBlockStyle}"/>
            <ComboBox Width="360" Margin="1,0" ItemsSource="{Binding MyProductTypes}" DisplayMemberPath="Code" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProductType, Mode=TwoWay}" TabIndex="0" />





            <Button x:Name="btnSave" Content=" Save " Margin="25,0,5,0" Command="{Binding SaveCommand, Mode=OneWay}" TabIndex="31" />

            <Button Content=" Clear " Command="{Binding ClearCommand, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0,0,5,0" TabIndex="34"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="24"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="23"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="14*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="71*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <Grid Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" >

            <TextBlock  Grid.Column="6" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Style="{DynamicResource SysdateMessageStyle}" Text="{Binding SystemDateMessage, Mode=OneWay}" Height="16" Width="0" />
            <TextBlock  Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="T1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Style="{DynamicResource HeadingStyle}" Grid.RowSpan="1" Margin="1,10,0,0" Height="23" Width="112"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Row="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="T2" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultTextBlockStyle}" Height="18" Width="61"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Row="4" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="T3" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultTextBlockStyle}" Height="18" Width="89"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Row="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="T4" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultTextBlockStyle}" Height="18" Width="103"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Row="6" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="T5" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultTextBlockStyle}" Height="18" Width="197"/>



            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Row="7" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="T6" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultTextBlockStyle}" Height="18" Width="103"/>

            <TextBox Name="txtTargetTicker1" Grid.Column="3" IsEnabled="{Binding EnableDealView}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Row="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Text="{Binding F1}" Style="{DynamicResource TargetTickerStyle}" TabIndex="2"/>

            <TextBox Name="txtTargetTicker" Grid.Column="3" IsEnabled="{Binding F2}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Row="4" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Text="{Binding F3}" Style="{DynamicResource TargetTickerStyle}" TabIndex="2"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="3" IsEnabled="{Binding F4}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="1,21,0,0" Grid.Row="4" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Text="{Binding F5}" Style="{DynamicResource AcquirerTickerStyle}" TabIndex="3" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>

            <TextBox Grid.Column="3" IsEnabled="{Binding F6}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Row="6" Width="155" Text="{Binding F7}" TabIndex="4"/>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="3" IsEnabled="{Binding F8}" Grid.Row="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,3,0,0" Width="250" Height="22">
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" IsEnabled="{Binding F9}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Row="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Style="{DynamicResource AcquirerTickerStyle}" TabIndex="3"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Row="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultTextBlockStyle}" Height="18" Width="75" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Run Text="Asset Currency"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding F10}"/>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Row="4" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultTextBlockStyle}" Height="18" Width="87" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Run Text="Manager"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding F11}"/>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,1,0,5" Grid.Row="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultTextBlockStyle}" Width="53" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Run Text="Bid Value"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding F12}"/>
            </TextBlock>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Row="6" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Country of risk" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultTextBlockStyle}" Height="18" Width="120" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>


        </Grid>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}">
                <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:VM1}">
                        <Views:View1/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:VM2}">
                        <Views:View2/>
                    </DataTemplate>                  
                </ContentPresenter.Resources>
            </ContentPresenter>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Your layout definitely needs some cleaning up to be sensible to work with. You have way too many columns and rows in your Grid. You should be grouping controls into organized sub-containers like nested StackPanels and such. This is going to be a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: For starters, that big list of controls isn't even inside the grid that has all your columns and rows defined. You put it all inside a nested grid that has no columns and rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I missing here please?

Don't put the `ContentPresenter` inside the `Grid`?

Fact is, without a good [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's impossible to say for sure. But based on what you posted, it sure looks like you've simply put the control in the wrong place in the XAML.

I.e. the layout should be something like this:

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="28" Width="auto" Margin="5,0,0,0">
        <!-- contents of StackPanel -->
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" >
        <!-- contents of inner Grid -->
    </Grid>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" Grid.Row="2">
        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:VM1}">
                <Views:View1/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:VM2">
                <Views:View2/>
            </DataTemplate>                  
        </ContentPresenter.Resources>
    </ContentPresenter>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Peter.Sorry, I tried the same but no luck.